# SciPy Minimize with monotonically decreasing Xs constraint

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am looking to do a strenuous optimization in which I use SciPy to optimize discount factors for bond cashflows (application less important, but if interested). So essentially I take multiple known values 'P', where P[i] is a function of C[i] known constant, and array X (X[j]=x(t) where x is a function of time). where the sum-product of C[i] and X = P.

Hope that makes some sense, but essentially in order for a sensible result, I want to put a constraint where X (my array of x values) has the constraint that x[j] < x[j-1], that is, x's are monotonically decreasing.

Here is my code snippet for the optimization function:

In [400]:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as s

def MyOptimization(X):
     P=np.array([99.,100.,105.,110.]) #just example known "P" array, in reality closer to 40 values
     c=np.array([1.25,4.,3.1,2.5]) #Cash flows for each P
     t=np.array([[1.2,2.,4.,10.0],[0.5,1.],[2.3,5.,10.5],[1.7]])   #time t of each cash flow, multiple per 'P'
                                                        #remember P=X(t)*c[i] and x(t) where x[i+1]<x[i]

     tlist=[] #t's will be used as index, so pulling individual values
     for i in t:
         for j in i:
             tlist.append(j)

     df=pd.DataFrame(data=X,index=tlist).drop_duplicates().sort() #dataframe to hold t (index) and x, x(t), and P(x,c) where c is known
     #print df
     sse=0
     for i in range(0,len(P)):
         pxi = np.sum(df.loc[t[i],0].values*c[i])+100*df.loc[t[i][-1],0]

         sse=sse+(pxi-P[i])**2 #want to minimize sum squared errors between calculated P(x,c) and known P
     return sse

cons=({'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x: x[1] < x[0]}) #trying to define constraint that x is decreasing with t

opti=s.optimize.minimize(MyOptimization,x0=[0.90,0.89,0.88,0.87,0.86,0.85,0.84,0.83,0.82,0.81],bounds=([0,1],)*10,constraints=cons)
```

In [401]:

```
opti
```

Out[401]:

```
status: 0
success: True
njev: 4
nfev: 69
 fun: 5.445290696814009e-15
   x: array([ 0.90092322,  0.89092322,  0.88092322,  0.94478062,  0.86301329,
    0.92834564,  0.84444848,  0.83444848,  0.96794781,  1.07317073])
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
 jac: array([ -7.50609263e-05,  -7.50609263e-05,  -7.50609263e-05,
    -5.92906077e-03,   3.46914830e-04,   9.17475767e-03,
    -4.89504256e-04,  -4.89504256e-04,  -1.61263312e-02,
     8.35321580e-03,   0.00000000e+00])
 nit: 4
```

And it is clear to see where in the results the x array is not decreasing. (tried adding (0,1) bounds as well but result failed, so focussing on this for now.

The important line here for the constraint that I'm really not sure about is:

`cons=({'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x: x[1] < x[0]})`

I tried following the documentation, but clearly it hasn't worked.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the values correct and you want to change their order?  Or are these not the values you were expecting.  If the numbers are good, but in the wrong order, you can call `sorted(my_list, reverse=True)` to put them in decreasing order

Comment: To me it seems as though they can't be correct because they don't satisfy the constraint that x[i] < x[i-1], so that x's are decreasing. as you can see the last x is higher than all the others. Although it maybe as simple as my constraint definition is completely wrong (I don't have a whole lot of experience with lambda functions).

In terms of "correct" they are technically correct if error is 0, but practically they are not correct unless the constraint is satisfied. the example may not result in a practical solution, but the real application should - just trying to get cons to work here

Comment: I'm reading the documentation for scipy.optimize.minimize, and it looks like you should be setting your constraint up so that it returns a non negative number on a pass.  Maybe try `lambda x: x[0] - x[1]`

Comment: That might let through numbers of the same value, so you probably need another constraint to handle those.

Comment: You're returning a boolean value.  I think you're supposed to be returning a numeric one.  From the documentation : Equality constraint means that the constraint function result is to be zero whereas inequality means that it is to be non-negative

Comment: Try lambda x: x[0] - x[1] 

(No < 0 )

Comment: you are onto something... when i switch those between x[1]-x[0] and x[0]-x[1] it does cause my first two values to flip between increasing/decreasing (not exact same values of course)... although ultimately I'm focussed on all x's. so x[i-1]-x[i]. I guess I'm looking at how to write that as a constraint... can i iterate to write a constraint based on the length of my x0? or is there an easy way to write it similarly to x[i-1]-x[i] that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try

```
def con(x):
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        if x[i] <= x[i+1]:
            return -1
    return 1

cons=({'type':'ineq','fun': con})
```

This should reject lists that aren't set up like you want, but I'm not sure is scipy is going to like it.

Comment: no luck unfortunately.it still "solves" but just looks like it doesn't use a constraint

Comment: I may have gotten closer with something like:
`constest=[]
for i in range(0,9):
    constest.append({'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x: x[i]-x[i+1]})
constest=tuple(constest) ` but still not returning decreasing x values...

Comment: What problems is that giving you?

Comment: `status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 6
    nfev: 87
     fun: 2.4160614409943012e-07
       x: array([ 0.90092506,  0.89092506,  0.88092506,  0.94477693,  0.86301945,
        0.92834855, -1.3189858 , -1.3289858 ,  1.09804772,  1.07317062])` the return is different from the original, but not constrained how I'd like, as the values are not decreasing

Comment: If i just hardcode the constraints as u initially said, i get all values equal (maybe a success?) not sure why loop wouldnt work: `cons=({'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x:x[0]-x[1]},
      {'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x:x[1]-x[2]},
      {'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x:x[2]-x[3]},
      {'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x:x[3]-x[4]},
      {'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x:x[4]-x[5]},
      {'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x:x[5]-x[6]},
      {'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x:x[6]-x[7]},
      {'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x:x[7]-x[8]},
      {'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x:x[8]-x[9]})`

Comment: `tuple([{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[i] - x[i+1]} for i in range(9)] + [{'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: 0 if x[j] != x[j+1] else 1} for j in range(9)])`  Try this.  The list comprehensions should build two lists of dictionaries. + combines them into one. Hopefully the second list of dictionaries will keep us from having equal values

Comment: hmmm. you might be on to something, it does accept that as a constraint, although does not find a solution and returns the original guess as the Xs and the message:  
`message: 'Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem'`

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the post below, but you need to have an `i=i` in there... `tuple([{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x,i=i: x[i] - x[i+1]} for i in range(9)] + [{'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x,i=i: 0 if x[j] != x[j+1] else 1} for j in range(9)])`